# What's the proper way to use the Python module scholar.py?

Tags: python, python-module, google-scholar

I'm kind of new to both Python and the command line, but I'm trying to use the Python module https://github.com/ckreibich/scholar.py/blob/master/README.md in order to fetch certain results from Google Scholar. After a few changes (it couldn't find the module) think I succeeded with the `import`, at least I didn't get any error message (but no confirmation).

But then what to do? I tried writing `scholar.py -c 1 --author "albert einstein" --phrase "quantum theory"` both inside and outside of Python, but only get error messages such as:

> File "", line 1
>       scholar.py -c 1 --author "albert einstein" --phrase "quantum theory"
>                     ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(The ^points to 1).

What is the proper way to use the module? Have I missed something?

Comment: You shouldn't write that line inside python itself, that command is meant to be used only on the command line. What happens when you try there?

Comment: Ok! In the command line, I get the error: "-bash: scholar.py: command not found"

Comment: I gave a more detailed answer below

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to write a command intended for the command line inside of python, you can't do that, and that's why you're setting `SyntaxError'

The problem you are having at the command line as specified in your comment:

> "-bash: scholar.py: command not found"

Is due to the fact that linux can't run commands like that that don't have executable permissions and are not in `PATH`. The easiest solution is to run it with `python`, but obviously make sure first that you're in the same folder as the `scholar.py` file, and then:

```
python scholar.py -c 1 --author "albert einstein" --phrase "quantum theory"
```

If that fails, perhaps the code only runs with `python3`, in which case try:

```
python3 scholar.py -c 1 --author "albert einstein" --phrase "quantum theory"
```

If you insist on running just the script without the `python` or `python3` commands, you should normally add the "python shebang" at the start of the file, with `#! /usr/bin/env python` or `#! /usr/bin/env python3` but I see that is already in the file. The next step is to set the file as executable:

```
chmod 770 scholar.py
```

Or if that fails, use `sudo` permissions to change the file permissions and ownership (requires root permissions, replace "youruser" with your actual username):

```
sudo chown youruser scholar.py
sudo chmod 770 scholar.py
```

And then you can run it like this, from the command line:

```
./scholar.py -c 1 --author "albert einstein" --phrase "quantum theory"
```